# Oracle SQL TABLE Operator with Global User-Defined Types showing "expression is of wrong type"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a package called `testingPackage`. It has a Function called `ToDo` with a Associative Array input parameter `arrPhoneType`.

When doing `testingPackage.ToDo('Kitty',arrTest)`, *expression is of wrong type error* is appeared.

How can I input a associative array value to the user-defined type?

**testingPackage.sql**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE testingPackage
AS

    TYPE PHONE IS RECORD
        (
        lfMobileNumber      NUMBER,
        lfPhoneNumber       NUMBER
        );
    TYPE arrPhoneType IS TABLE OF PHONE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
    INTS arrPhoneType;

    FUNCTION ToDo
        (
        szName          IN VARCHAR2,
        szList          IN arrPhoneType DEFAULT CAST(NULL AS arrPhoneType)
        )
    RETURN VARCHAR2;
END testingPackage;
/
```

**testingFunction.sql**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE testingFunction
...
END testingFunction;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY testingFunction
AS
    FUNCTION FunctionA
    RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS
        szResult            VARCHAR2(2000);
        arrTest             testingPackage.arrPhoneType;
    BEGIN
        arrTest(0).lfMobileNumber := 12345678;
        arrTest(0).lfPhoneNumber := 87654321;
        
        SELECT  NVL(testingPackage.ToDo('Kitty',arrTest),'')
        INTO    szResult
        FROM    Dual;

        RETURN szResult;
    END FunctionA;
END testingFunction;
/
```

Comment: I'm not getting a compilation error if I fill in the package bodies and specs that I'd expect you'd have https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/mady3v12qaak6sbda0jwo1n1j

Comment: @JustinCave Tried the code in link, showing "Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors." on my environment. Do you know what happen? Thx

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  Can you reproduce the issue on, say, livesql.oracle.com or dbfiddle?

Comment: As a stylistic matter, I'd virtually always prefer `szResult := nvl( testingPackage ...` to doing a `select from dual`.  That might also work on an old version of Oracle where a `select from dual` would not but I don't have an old version to test that theory.

Comment: @JustinCave My environment is Oracle Database 11g, and szResult := nvl( testingPackage ... is OK for me!!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stylistically, it is virtually always preferable to do a direct assignment than to do a `select` from `dual`.  Since you're on an older version of Oracle, that would also resolve the compilation issue you have since the old SQL engine wasn't able to cope with collections defined in PL/SQL.

Here's a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=228a5ea650da24238c7b570becc5e044) showing that if you're using Oracle 11g R2 and change the line to

```
szResult :=  NVL(testingPackage.ToDo('Kitty',arrTest),'') ;
```

the code should compile